# Removing a prepended script tag with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, append

I am loading Google Maps script into my site on click and I want to be able to remove that script on click of another button so that I don't end up with multiple Google Maps scripts if the user keeps loading different maps. How can I do this? Do I target by the src of the script tag or can I add a class/ID or something?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.add-script').click(function() {
    $('body').append('<script class="gmaps-script" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&callback=init"></script>');
  });
  
  $('.remove-script').click(function() {
    // Remove previously appended script tag here
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-script">Load Map</button>
<button class="remove-script">Remove Map</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the last script Tag with

```
$('script').last().remove();
```

Or give the script tag an id like `id="gmaps-js"` and remove it with `$('#gmaps-js').remove()`